# My htaccess is appending page name to redirected url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have just redone my site from WordPress to html and set it to non-www from www.
My redirects are playing up though.
My htaccess is set up as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [NC,R,L]

Redirect 301 /category/wp-page-name/ https://domain-name/page-name.html
```

The 301 is redirecting to:
https://domain-name/page-name.htmlwp-page-name

it is appending the old WordPress page name to the re-directed address.

I have tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/wp-page-name/?$ https://domain-name/page-name.html
```

and

```
 RewriteRule ^/?category/wp-page-name/?$ https://domain-name/page-name.html [L,R=301]
```

No redirect occurs although I am not sure whether the initial faulty redirects have been cached.

I would be grateful for any advice

Comment: I would do this redirect via a RewriteRule as well. The two directives are provided by different modules, and by mixing them, you can easily run into surprises regarding execution order.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, could you give me an eg of the Rewrite rule I would use?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^category/wp-page-name/$ /page-name.html [R=301,L]` should do the trick.

Comment: No joy  CBroe - 404 - it's not even re-writing the www to non www

Comment: Where did you put it? RewriteConds only affect the following rule, so you must not take the existing RewriteCond + RewriteRule that are in charge of the domain redirect apart here.

Comment: I put the rewrite rule you suggested immediately underneath the  rewrite rule for the www to non-www rule and index.html  rule.

Comment: Hi CBroe, also tried it immediately after the initial RewriteEngine On statement, again a 404